# DrawerLayout - ClassNotFoundException while compiling with Android Studio and Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library, drawerlayout

I was trying to create a sample app using the new DrawerLayout with the Android Studio and Gradle. I am referring the official google document mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). But whenever I launch the app, it exits with an exception (ClassNotFoundException - DrawerLayout).

I have installed the latest support library from SDK manager (support-v4-13.0.0.jar) and it's automatically added to dependencies by the IDE. I tried copying this jar to the libs folder of project and changed the reference in the Libraries in "Project Structure". But still getting the error.

Here is the "dependencies" section from my build.gradle

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}`

What I am missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a little weird, but I could figure it out.

I Just replaced the inclusion of DrawerLayout in the layout XML from

`<DrawerLayout> .... </DrawerLayout>`

to

`<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> ... </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`

And this fixed the issue.

Comment: I have been breaking my head for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks!  Android can be so kooky with this stuff.